# Evaluate a lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda

I have a class

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a lambda expression of the Person type

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
```

Who contains this value

```
{model => model.Name}
```

How can I evaluate that lambda expression against an instance of Person, to extract the Name value attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compile the expression into a delegate and pass in a `Person` object:

```
Func<Person, string> getName = expression.Compile();
string name = getName(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Expression trees:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx